# Index hinting in Doctrine2

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

Is there a way to hint the use of an index in Doctrine2? The equivalent of the MySQL USE INDEX syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM user u USE INDEX(my_super_index) ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a gist with working code using a custom tree walker: https://gist.github.com/arnaud-lb/2704404

Thanks to the author!

It will not work for RDBMS using a different syntax than MySQL though.

**Update:** The previous code does not work for queries with multiple tables in the FROM clause. So here is my updated version of the previous walker:

```
<?php

namespace __YOUR_NAMESPACE_;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

class UseIndexWalker extends SqlWalker
{
    const HINT_USE_INDEX = 'UseIndexWalker.UseIndex';

    public function walkFromClause($fromClause)
    {
        $sql = parent::walkFromClause($fromClause);
        $index = $this->getQuery()->getHint(self::HINT_USE_INDEX);

        return preg_replace('/( INNER JOIN| LEFT JOIN|$)/', sprintf(' USE INDEX(%s)\1', $index), $sql, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that when you implements this  on a Query in a repository in Symfony, you have to set FDQN for the value of the Hint Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER

```
<?php

namespace __YOUR_NAMESPACE_\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query;
use __YOUR_NAMESPACE_\UseIndexWalker;

class MyEntityRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function myFunction()
    {
        $query = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()->select('my_field')->from('my_entity', 'my_entity')->getQuery();
        $query->setHint(Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER, UseIndexWalker::class);
        $query->setHint(UseIndexWalker::HINT_USE_INDEX, 'my_super_index');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one: https://github.com/shipmonk-rnd/doctrine-mysql-index-hints

```php
$queryBuilder
    ->getQuery()
    ->setHint(Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER, UseIndexSqlWalker::class)
    ->setHint(UseIndexSqlWalker::class, [IndexHint::use(User::INDEX_NAME, User::TABLE_NAME)])
    ->getResult();
```